# Add pixel data to Bitmap object in native c code

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I have a bitmap object in my native code i.e. "jobject bitmap" and i have a pointer say "*ptr" which points to a decoded frame data. Can someone tell me how i can add these pixel data pointed by ptr to the bitmap object so that i can pass this object to the android code and display the data present in the bitmap.

Also is there anyway to display the frame from the native c code itself. Any valuable suggestions/answers will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance please help.

Comment: Just a little clarification: Are you trying to get pass image data from Java -> C and manipulate the image via C? Or vice versa? What type of image manipulation are you hoping to perform?

Comment: @Mike: Thanks for the reply. I have a buffer which contains the pixel information/ Data of a decoded frame. This buffer is in the c code. I need to pass these values to java so that i can display it.